# How to set a cookie through a header?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

In my acceptance test, I am trying to send a JSON request with a cookie:

```php
// CartTest.php
$response = $this->postJson(route('carts.store'), [], [
    'Cookie' => 'uuid='.Crypt::encrypt($cart->uuid)
]);
```

When I do `$request->hasCookie('uuid')` at the controller, I get `false`.

I also tried different variations, like `Set-Cookie`, `HTTP_SET_COOKIE`, etc. but none of them seem to work. I'd prefer to pass the cookie with `postJson` instead of the generic `call` for brevity.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried HTTP_COOKIE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand now why Laravel does not accept any cookies in its `postJson` method signature. In fact, [it's not a recommended practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141019/should-cookies-be-used-in-a-restful-api) to exchange cookies with an API in the first place. That answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this? Before making a request:

```
$_COOKIE['uuid'] = Crypt::encrypt($cart->uuid);
```

Yes, it is bold. But seems to works as well. Also there are [other ideas](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/setting-cookies-before-test)